# Is it normal for a java program to run at 60M or 90M?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a proxy server program which listens on a socket and creates a thread pool to process connections which come in spawning new threads if necessary to handle any additional overhead. When I start up the program on java 1.5 its memory footprint is 90M while if I use a java 1.6 jvm, it has a 60M footprint, this seems larger large for a simple proxy server program, is it normal?

I ask this because the system has rather limited memory and sometimes it throws OutOfMemoryException.

Above statistics are for when i start off with an initial thread pool size of less than 10. I I increase the initial thread pool size to 50, its memory footprint on jvm 1.5 is around 120M.

How can I reduce the memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems about right for a small Java process - remember, Java isn't really an ideal choice if you are looking for a really small memory footprint.

You should remember that the JVM is a Stack-based machine, where each thread gets its own Stack.

The size of the stack differs depending on what type of JVM you are running - (I believe, since I've lost the page from oracle.com which detailed these values) a 32bit JVM runs each thread with a 320kb stack, while the 64bit JVM assigns 1Mb per thread - this explains why having a large thread pool increases the memory size.

Aside from the Stack, the JVM also allocates memory space for the Heap - Stack space is not usually allocated from the Heap, so all this mounts up.

If you are blowing your memory limits, you can try limiting the usage, by the use of the command line switches when you start the Java application.

```
java -Xmx100m -Xss128k <followed by your other usual params>
```

- `-Xmx` is used to limit the max heap size (eg. `-Xmx100m` would limit the heap to 100Mb.
- `-Xss` is used to limit the stack size assigned to each Thread (eg. `-Xmx128k` would limit each stack to 128Kb).

There are other tuning parameters you can use, however you should be careful when limiting memory as you may cause issues with your application.

Garbage collection is another area that can be tuned, to help with memory usage, but I won't go into that area on such a small application.

As mentioned by Ingo, I would recommend you use a profiler against your application to see where the memory is being allocated - many of the popular IDEs either have a profiler built in, or have them available as plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a tool that helps you analyze the memory requirements of your program.

You may want to look into `jvisualvm`, for example.
You can watch memory allocations live or take a snapshot and analyse memory consumption on a class by class basis.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fairly normal. If memory footprint is critical is it is worth trying different JVMs as they could be either more efficient or bloated. You could try decreasing the thread stack and TLAB allocation sizes to reduce the per thread overhead.

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty common size.  Obvious answer - use java 1.6 where you get lower memory footprint.  To determine where your memory is gone, you will need to do profiling.